# Automatic table width doesn't work anymore

Tags: tables, tabularx, ltablex

I got an odd problem since yesterday.
I'm writing my thesis with Lyx. I'm using a template based on the KOMA-Script.

Well, yesterday I've deleted a number of tables from my document. After compiling again, I've received following error message:

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

The error occurs on a row of consecutive tables, which are positioned directly after the deleted tables. Before that, they worked without any problems. I'm using the `tabularx` package for the tables.

The tables are defined like the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\MPT{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\columncolor{Gray}}lX|} 
\hline % oberste Linie, vor erster Spalte
\rowcolor{Gray}
\textbf{Blabla} & \textbf{} \\ \hline \hline
IST-Zustand
& 
\vspace{-1\topsep}
\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{4mm}\setlength{\topsep}{0mm}} 
\MPT
\item blaaa
\end{list}
\vspace{-1\topsep} ~
\\ \hline
\caption{blabla}
\end{tabularx}
```

After a long time of trying I found out, that when I replace the columns which are defined with `X`, by a fix column width like `p{...cm}`, it suddenly works again.

Is this somehow explainable without any working example (I could hand one in later)?

Edit:

Here's the preambel of my document:

```
% verschieden Symbole, Zeichen wie (c), €
\usepackage{textcomp}


\usepackage{ %a4wide,
            ellipsis, fixltx2e, mparhack,   %Fehlerkorrektur für Marginalien
            booktabs, longtable             %schönere Tabellen
}  

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
%\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\\\headmark}
\ihead{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{pics/logo_schwarz.pdf}}%\pagemark}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}


%Kurzfassung und Abstract (englisch) auf eine Seite
\renewenvironment{abstract}{
    \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}
        \normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}
}{
    \par
}



% schönerer Blocksatz!!
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{ifpdf} % part of the hyperref bundle
\ifpdf % if pdflatex is used

%set fonts for nicer pdf view
 \IfFileExists{lmodern.sty}{\usepackage{lmodern}}
  {\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \usepackage{courier} }
\fi

 % the pages of the TOC are numbered roman
 % and a pdf-bookmark for the TOC is added
 \pagenumbering{roman}
 \let\myTOC\tableofcontents
 \renewcommand\tableofcontents{
   %\pdfbookmark[1]{Contents}{}
   \myTOC
   \clearpage
   \pagenumbering{arabic}}

%Bezeichungen anpassen
%Babelpaket muß zuvor geladen werden
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\addto\captionsngerman{ 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}% 
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}% 
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Kurzfassung}
%\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungen}
}

% Alle Querverweise und URLs als Link darstellen
% In der PDF-Ausgabe
 \usepackage[colorlinks=true, bookmarks, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen, bookmarksopenlevel=1,
  linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, filecolor=blue,
  pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true,
  pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels,
  pdfauthor={LyX Team}, pdftex,
  pdftitle={LyX's Figure, Table, Floats, Notes, and Boxes manual},
  pdfsubject={LyX-documentation about figures, tables, floats, notes, and boxes},
  pdfkeywords={LyX, Tables, Figures, Floats, Boxes, Notes}]{hyperref}

%mehr Platz zwischen Überschrift und Tabelle
\newcommand{\@ldtable}{}
\let\@ldtable\table
\renewcommand{\table}{ %
                 \setlength{\@tempdima}{\abovecaptionskip} %
                 \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\belowcaptionskip} %
                 \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\@tempdima} %
                 \@ldtable}

%Farbigen Hintergrund erstellen
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}



%Tabularx package
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow, rotating, array, paralist}
\usepackage{caption}

%damit URLs als solche erkannt werden
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig} %damit grafiken umflossen werden
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

@Marco Daniel:

Here's the log file:

...

```
Package caption Info: KOMA-Script document class.
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count114
Package caption Info: hyperref package is loaded.
Package caption Info: longtable package is loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\ltcaption.sty"
Package: ltcaption 2013/02/03 v1.3-62 longtable captions (AR)
)
Package caption Info: rotating package is loaded.
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\wrapfig\wrapfig.sty"
\wrapoverhang=\dimen140
\WF@size=\dimen141
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count115
\WF@box=\box32
\WF@everypar=\toks24
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrhack.sty"
Package: scrhack 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (hacking other packages)

Package scrhack Info: hyperref hack deactivated because of
(scrhack)             detection of hyperref version, that doesn't
(scrhack)             need that hack, on input line 131.
)
No file Neues_Dokument1.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 116.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 116.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 116.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\t1lmr.fd"
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 116.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 116.
Package microtype Info: Generating PDF output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: Automatic font expansion enabled (level 2),
(microtype)             stretch: 20, shrink: 20, step: 1, non-selected.
Package microtype Info: Using default expansion set `basictext'.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of interword spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of character kerning.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\microtype\mt-cmr.cfg"
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman 
(RS)
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box33
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 116.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count116
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 116.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 116.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 116.

(C:\Users\Marin\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.p10112\lyx_tmpbuf4\Neues_Dokument
1.out)
(C:\Users\Marin\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.p10112\lyx_tmpbuf4\Neues_Dokument
1.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count117
\scratchdimen=\dimen142
\scratchbox=\box34
\nofMPsegments=\count118
\nofMParguments=\count119
\everyMPshowfont=\toks25
\MPscratchCnt=\count120
\MPscratchDim=\dimen143
\MPnumerator=\count121
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count122
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks26
)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: wrapfig package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\ot1lmr.fd") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTe
X 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omllmm.fd") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omslm
sy.fd") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omxlmex.fd")
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 \end{tabularx}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 161
 []

[1

{C:/Users/Marin/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 163.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 163.

(C:\Users\Marin\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.p10112\lyx_tmpbuf4\Neues_Dokument
1.aux

Package mparhack Warning: Marginpars may have changed.
(mparhack)                Rerun to get them right.

)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 163.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 163.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `Neues_Dokument1.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 163.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11186 strings out of 493921
 176087 string characters out of 3147282
 326371 words of memory out of 3000000
 14277 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 23043 words of font info for 44 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 40i,12n,46p,526b,439s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathsy.enc}{C:/Program Fil
es/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/t
ype1/public/lm/lmbx10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lm
r10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmsy10.pfb>
Output written on Neues_Dokument1.pdf (1 page, 64188 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 27 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 4 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 5633 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you aren't providing a minimal working example.

The error based on the package `ltablex`. The documentation provides the following hint:

> Another feature that has been added is to treat the X columns like ‘l’ columns if the table contents would allow that to happen without exceeding the specified width of the table.

Inside the column type `l` list environments aren't allowed. So you get an error. You can suppress this redefinition by saying: `\keepXColumns`.

So my mwe can be modified as:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\keepXColumns
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\MPT{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{blabla}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\columncolor{gray}}lX|} 
\hline % oberste Linie, vor erster Spalte
\rowcolor{gray}
\textbf{Blabla} & \textbf{} \\ \hline \hline
IST-Zustand
& 
\MPT\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{4mm}\setlength{\topsep}{0mm}} 
\item blaaa
\end{list}
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Original answer

I took your code snippet and provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) with the following modifications:

- I placed the `\caption` command outside of `tabularx`.
- I put everything in the floatings object `table`
- I put the command `\MPT` in front of `list``
- I removed `\vspace`:

Here the example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\MPT{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{blabla}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\columncolor{gray}}lX|} 
\hline % oberste Linie, vor erster Spalte
\rowcolor{gray}
\textbf{Blabla} & \textbf{} \\ \hline \hline
IST-Zustand
& 
\MPT\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{4mm}\setlength{\topsep}{0mm}} 
\item blaaa
\end{list}
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still same error. As I mentioned, everything was working fine until I removed the other tables. I think there could be a clash between the packages I'm using, but couldn't figure it out yet

Comment: @Marinko: Did the example work for you?

Comment: No, as I said: Still same error when using your example. I've added the preambel in my first post. maybe there's the problem.

Comment: @Marinko: My example works well. Please compile the example and show us your log file.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, your example works. I've tried it in a new file. It just doesn't work within my existing document. That's why I suppose the mistake must be somewhere else. I'll post the log file...

Comment: I hope that's enough information of the log file

Comment: @Marinko: I edited my answer. However it's your task providing a mwe.

Comment: I just figured out the same. Yes, I'm sorry bout the mwe. Thought the problem could be solved differently..you tought me better. Thank you very much for your help!!